# What does it mean if a superclass state is not defined in Lisp?

Tags: class, common-lisp, superclass, clos

My superclass is defined as follows:

```
(defclass missionary-state (state)
  ((missionary-left :initarg :missionary-left :initform nil :accessor missionary-left
    :documentation "the number of missionaries on the left side of the river")
   (missionary-right :initarg :missionary-right :initform nil :accessor missionary-right
    :documentation "the number of missionaries on the right side of the river")
   (cannibal-left :initarg :cannibal-left :initform nil :accessor cannibal-left
    :documentation "the number of cannibals on the left side of the river")
   (cannibal-right :initarg :cannibal-right :initform nil :accessor cannibal-right
     :documentation "the number of cannibals on the right side of the river")
   (boat-pos :initarg :boat-pos :initform nil :accessor boat-pos 
    :documentation "the side the boat is on")))
```

This is the error message that I get after trying to loading it:

```
Error: Class #<STANDARD-CLASS MISSIONARY-STATE>
       can't be finalized because superclass STATE
       is not defined yet
```

Comment: What is `defclass missionary-state (state)` supposed to do?

Comment: To define the missionary-state class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation for [`defclass`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defcla.htm) it is clear that you are creating `missionary-state` by extending the parent class `state`.

Now the error message gives an indication that you have tried to make an instance of `missionary-state` before defining `missionary-state`'s parent class `state`. It is not a standard class so you need to tell the system what that is.

If you didn't intend it so be a sub class of `state` you just remove the parent class in the definition:

```
(defclass missionary-state ()
  ...)
```

Now it's a direct sub class of `standard-object` and `standard-class`.

Comment: What is it referring to in your last sentence?

Comment: @Michelle If you create a class with a empty list of parents it will always inherit from `standard-object` and `standard-class`. If the parent list is `(state)` then the state class is the parent and it will most likely have the already mentioned classes as its parents.

Comment: What does the standard-object and standard-class have?

Comment: @Michelle See [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_std_ob.htm) and the excellent [Practical Common Lisp chapter about classes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html)

Answer (score 2):

> My superclass is defined as follows:
>
> (defclass missionary-state (state)

That's not a superclass. At least we don't know that it is one. It could be one, if you inherit from this class. What you do is this:

- define a class `missionary-state`
- the class has a superclass `state`
- the superclass `state` is not a part of your example, thus undefined.

Common Lisp allows you to define classes which have undefined superclasses. You even don't need to tell Common Lisp that `state` is a class and that it will be defined later.

But you need to define the class `state` before you make instances of that class or its subclasses. The error message tells you that Lisp can't finalize the class `missionary-state`, because the class `state` does not exist yet - the name is known, but there is no definition for it.

Usually you would just define the class `state` and then create the instances. If that is **not** possible, then you can also do this:

- define the class `missionary-state` without listing `state` as a superclass.
- create instances of the class `missionary-state`
- define the class `state`
- redefine the class `missionary-state` to have the superclass `state`

This will then update existing instances and will also make sure future instances to use the information from the updated class incl. the superclass. This is possible, because CLOS (the Common Lisp Object System) allows various runtime updates to the class graph.

Comment: Thank you for the clear response. I realized I forgot to load and compile another file before loading my file. That was why my superclass state was undefined.